# Changing Logo URL on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Don't think I've posted here before! I'm not much of a designer/coder so I wanted to ask for some help with php.

I'm using Wordpress and the Avada theme. I put together a layout I like within the framework. I found it pretty easy to use a header with the menu and theme together but the logo itself is the in the slider so I don't really need it there. What I used in it's place is the phone number image.

Is there a way to modify some PHP (maybe functions.php) so the logo now links to the phone number? (ie. tel:7327036593).

Thanks for any pointers. I tried messing around with it a little but I just broke the site several times! :)

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: The short answer: yes. The long answer: it is almost impossible to say what you have to change where, without the framework and configuration. I'd recommend to ask this question on the Avada forum.

Answer (score 0):

## Changing the href for the Avada Theme Logo Image

If you install ShortCode Exec PHP plugins then you can use it to create the following shortcode:

```
?><script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("div.fusion-logo a").attr("href","tel:303-985-9850");
});
</script>
```

I called it myjavascript.

Then you can navigate over to Appearance/Widgets and select one of footer widget areas and using a text widget add the following shortcode.

```
[myjavascript]
```

The selector may differ slightly from one version to another or if your using the retina 2x version or not.  But you can always figure it out using developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends if you're using a free template with limited access or a paid theme.

If you are using a paid theme, you can go into the theme options and look for the link of your logo. You will have to enter "tel:(xxx)xxx-xxx" in place of a url link.

If you are comfortable working with PHP, you can modify the header.php file in a editor like notepad ++, sublime, or dreamweaver.

If you aren't big on PHP, you can use a wordpress plugin to help modify your logo url. Always make sure that the plugin you use is 1)compatible with the current wordpress setup 2)allows you to work with a method you're comfortable with 3)has many reviews/downloads.